# Adding a custom full-stack web page within a Wordpress website in Godaddy

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress

I have a separate full-stack website which is made of HTML,CSS,JS and NodeJs. I want to add this website **within a webpage of an another website**,which is developed using wordpress in Godaddy. How to intergrate the **custom full-stack website** within the **wordpress website**?
The wordpress website is currently running on goDaddy.

Comment: sound like an iFrame

Comment: No,not using an iFrame.I want to intergrate that piece of code within the source code of the wordpress website.